# Magnetic Shielding

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles

Imagine a substance in an electric field. You don't want the electric field to interact with the object you have put in its way. What should be the type of material this magnet should be made of to stop the effect of "magnetic shielding"?

Paramagnetic
Diamagnetic 
or Ferromagnetic ?

My theory was paramagnetic, but I believe that isn't the answer since the field will pass straight through iy

Comment: In general a magnetic material will not shield an electric field. As it happens most ferromagnets are conductors, and conductors will shield an electric field (Google *Faraday shield*) but they aren't shielding the field because they are ferromagnetic - a ferromagnetic insulator will not shield an electric field.

Comment: how do I block the magnetic field @JohnRennie

Comment: [mu metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic shielding materials re-direct a magnetic field so it 
lessens the field's influence on the item being shielded. 
Shielding does not eliminate or destroy magnetic fields, 
nothing does. It does, however, provide an easy path for the 
magnetic field to complete its path. You may think of it as a 
magnetic field conductor.
This leads to what type of material can provide the best path 
for magnetic fields and thus create shielding. Since the field is 
attracted to the shielding material it stands to reason that if a 
magnet is attracted to the material (ferromagnetic material), 
that material can provide some amount of magnetic shielding.

Wiki link :-
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding&ved=2ahUKEwiRxLKsj-DeAhVbWX0KHcx6ALEQFjAMegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0QNCS7KA8EXUUgwTwY0uav&cshid=1542619297150